# How to check if batch http endpoint used for drive app in apps script

Tags: google-apps-script

For one of our apps script applications we got Google notification saying 
"Action Required:Migrate off Global HTTP Batch Endpoint"
Drive API v2.
but in the Apps script we are connecting to Drive using Driveapp only.

E.g: DriveApp.createFile('New Text File', 'Hello, world!');

and not explicitly making any api calls to drive api from javascript.
Could you please help how to check where the Global http batch end point used
for DriveApp in Apps Script?

Thanks,
Vivek

Comment: Check the associated Google Cloud Platform project - you may have generated additional credentials for the project and written associated code (e.g. web server worker, Python backend script) that uses these credentials to access the global batch endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

The global batch endpoint is as follows:

`https://www.googleapis.com/batch`

Unfortunately, the global batch endpoint was discontinued back in March of 2018 ([see announcement](https://developers.googleblog.com/2018/03/discontinuing-support-for-json-rpc-and.html)).

So somewhere in your code, your are either calling that URL endpoint directly or using a service or library that does.